# Getting all files in the android internal storage

Tags: android

I want to iterate through all the files in `/data/data/[app package]` in order to delete some files.

if I use:

```
val cw = ContextWrapper(applicationcontext)
val directory = cw.filesDir
```

The directory it gives me is `/data/user/0/[app package]/files` which returns zero list of files.

So I tried hardcoding the path in test (without the "files" directory):

```
 val x = File("/data/user/0/[package name]")
 val files = x.listFiles()
```

And I got the correct list of files returned. How do I access the correct internal storage path without the "files" directory being returned by `filesDir`? Is the correct solution to convert the path returned to string and truncate it to remove the "files" directory?